# default-rpath of ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: linux

Is there anyway to see the default-rpath hard coded into ld-linux-x86-64.so.2?

Basically when glibc is compiled/installed, it can take a default-rpath and thus hard coded into the loader binary.

Comment: Did you try using `strings` or `objdump` on your `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` ? And you also should look inside `/etc/ld.so.conf` etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, basically I want to know the exact order the program loader searches for the libraries.  My /etc/ld.so.conf only contains one entry, /usr/local/lib, and other environment variables are empty.  So other paths must have been hard coded into the loader itself.  That why I asked this problem.

Comment: You can `strace` a program to understand (dynamically) the order of library searches. It depends upon `/etc/ld.so.cache` hence of last run of `ldconfig`